# Socket issues in simple Scala TCP server

Tags: java, sockets, scala, tcp

I'm new to Scala so the question may be quite simple, though I have spent some time trying to resolve it. I have a simple Scala TCP server (no actors, single thread):

```
import java.io._
import java.net._

object Application {
  def readSocket(socket: Socket): String = {
    val bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream))
    var request = ""
    var line = ""
    do {
      line = bufferedReader.readLine()
      if (line == null) {
        println("Stream terminated")
        return request
      }
      request += line + "\n"
    } while (line != "")
    request
  }

  def writeSocket(socket: Socket, string: String) {
    val out: PrintWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream))
    out.println(string)
    out.flush()
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val port = 8000
    val serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)
    while (true) {
      val socket = serverSocket.accept()
      readSocket(socket)
      writeSocket(socket, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\nOK")
      socket.close()
    }
  }
}
```

The server listens on `localhost:8000` for incomming requests and sends HTTP response with single `OK` word in the body. Then I run Apache Benchmark like this:

```
ab -c 1000 -n 10000 http://localhost:8000/
```

which works nicely for the first time. The second time I start `ab` it hangs producing the following output in `netstat -a | grep 8000`:

```
....
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:43709 localhost.localdom:8000 FIN_WAIT2  
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:43711 localhost.localdom:8000 FIN_WAIT2  
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:43717 localhost.localdom:8000 FIN_WAIT2  
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:43777 localhost.localdom:8000 FIN_WAIT2  
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:43722 localhost.localdom:8000 FIN_WAIT2  
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:43725 localhost.localdom:8000 FIN_WAIT2  
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8000               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6      83      0 localhost.localdom:8000 localhost.localdo:43724 CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp6      83      0 localhost.localdom:8000 localhost.localdo:43786 CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp6       1      0 localhost.localdom:8000 localhost.localdo:43679 CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp6      83      0 localhost.localdom:8000 localhost.localdo:43735 CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp6      83      0 localhost.localdom:8000 localhost.localdo:43757 CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp6      83      0 localhost.localdom:8000 localhost.localdo:43754 CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp6      83      0 localhost.localdom:8000 localhost.localdo:43723 CLOSE_WAIT
....
```

Since that no more requests are served by the server. One more detail: The same `ab` script with the same parameters works smoothly testing a simple Node.js server on the same machine. So this issue is not related to a number of opened TCP connections which I have set to be reusable with

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=1
```

Could anyone give me a clue on what I'm missing?

**Edit**: Termination of stream handling has been added to the code above:

```
    if (line == null) {
      println("Stream terminated")
      return request
    }
```

Comment: CLOSE_WAIT means that TCP is waiting for that application to close its socket. Another problem is that you aren't sending the correct line terminators for HTTP. They are specified as \r\n, not \n.

Comment: I've updated the code to `\r\n` though `curl` and `ab` both seem to work fine with `\n`. As for CLOSE_WAIT - it doesn't seem to be the root of the problem. Thank you for commenting.

Comment: CLOSE_WAIT is a symptom of the problem that the application hasn't closed the socket.

Comment: I don't see where you are closing your input/output streams? Shouldn't those be closed after the execution of your system has finished?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to your problem. I am curious to find out what resolved it?

Comment: @sc_ray I've posted the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10810800/1196771).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting the (partial) answer to my own question for those who will stumble upon the same issue one day. First, the nature of the problem lies not in the source code but in the system itself which restricts numerious connections. The problem is that the `socket` passed to `readSocket` function appears corrupted under some conditions, i.e. it can not be read and `bufferedReader.readLine()` either returns `null` on first call or hangs indefinitely. The following two steps make the code working on some machines:

1. Increase the number of concurrent connections to a socket with

   ```
   sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=65535
   ```
2. Provide the second parameter to `ServerSocket` constructor which will explicitly set the length of connection queue:

   ```
   val maxQueue = 50000
   val serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port, maxQueue)
   ```

The steps above solve the problem on EC2 m1.large instances, however I'm still getting issues on my local machine. The better way would be to use [Akka](http://akka.io/) for the stuff of that kind:

```
import akka.actor._
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import akka.util.ByteString

class TCPServer(port: Int) extends Actor {

  override def preStart {
    IOManager(context.system).listen(new InetSocketAddress(port))
  }

  def receive = {
    case IO.NewClient(server) =>
      server.accept()
    case IO.Read(rHandle, bytes) => {
      val byteString = ByteString("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\nOK")
      rHandle.asSocket.write(byteString)
      rHandle.close()
    }
  }
}

object Application {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val port = 8000
    ActorSystem().actorOf(Props(new TCPServer(port)))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest trying this without `ab`.  You can do something like:

```
echo "I'm\nHappy\n" | nc -vv localhost 8000
```

Second, I'd suggest handling end-of-stream.  This is where `BufferedReader.readLine()` returns null.  The code above only checks for an empty String.  After you fix this, I'd try again.  Then test with ab, after everything looks good.  Let us know if the problem persists.

Comment: First, the code works in browser, curl, telnet etc. Second, `null` handling is not the root cause. In fact, in my situation it should only happen when the client closes connection which is not the case. I've updated the question to make it clear. Thanks for suggestions.